# A cocos2d-x code that cause crash on Android but not on iOS

Tags: cocos2d-x

While porting an cocos2d-x project from iOS to Android, I found a problem that will  cause crashing on Android but not on iOS, to show this problem, I made a small modification to the HelloWorld sample. To reproduce this problem, just press the close button on the bottom-right corner, on Android it will crash but not on iOS.

The code that cause the crashing is:

```
void TestNode::test()
{
    // This will cause crash on Android, but OK on iOS
    CCCallFunc *selector = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(TestNode::destroy));
    this->runAction(selector);

    // This is ok on both Android and iOS
//    CCCallFunc *selector = CCCallFunc::create(scene_, callfunc_selector(HelloWorld::destroyNode));
//    scene_->runAction(selector);

    // This is ok on both Android and iOS
//    destroy();
}
```

The complete code as the following:

HelloWorldScene.h

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h" 

class TestNode : public cocos2d::CCNode {
    public:
        TestNode(cocos2d::CCLayer *scene);
        ~TestNode();

        void test();
        void destroy();

        cocos2d::CCLayer *scene_;
        cocos2d::CCSprite *sprite_;
};

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
private:
    TestNode *node_;
public:
    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();  

    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);

    // implement the "static node()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

    void destroyNode();
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h" 
#include "AppMacros.h" 
USING_NS_CC;

TestNode::TestNode(cocos2d::CCLayer *scene):
    scene_(scene)
{
    sprite_ = CCSprite::create("CloseNormal.png");
    sprite_->setPosition(ccp(200, 200));
    scene_->addChild(sprite_, 255);
}

TestNode::~TestNode()
{
    scene_->removeChild(sprite_, true);
    scene_->removeChild(this, true);
    CCLog("+++ ~TestNode");
}

void TestNode::test()
{
    // This will cause crash on Android, but OK on iOS
    CCCallFunc *selector = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(TestNode::destroy));
    this->runAction(selector);

    // This is ok on both Android and iOS
//    CCCallFunc *selector = CCCallFunc::create(scene_, callfunc_selector(HelloWorld::destroyNode));
//    scene_->runAction(selector);

    // This is ok on both Android and iOS
//    destroy();
}

void TestNode::destroy()
{
    CCLog("+++ destroy");
    delete this;
}

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

    /////////////////////////////
    // 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
    //    you may modify it.

    // add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
    CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                        "CloseNormal.png",
                                        "CloseSelected.png",
                                        this,
                                        menu_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback));

    pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width - pCloseItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + pCloseItem->getContentSize().height/2));

    // create menu, it's an autorelease object
    CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
    pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
    this->addChild(pMenu, 1);

    /////////////////////////////
    // 3. add your codes below...

    // add a label shows "Hello World" 
    // create and initialize a label

    CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello World", "Arial", TITLE_FONT_SIZE);

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    pLabel->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - pLabel->getContentSize().height));

    // add the label as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(pLabel, 1);

    // add "HelloWorld" splash screen" 
    CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    pSprite->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(pSprite, 0);

    node_ = new TestNode(this);
    this->addChild(node_);

    return true;
}

void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
//    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();
    if (node_) {
        node_->test();
        node_ = NULL;
    }

//#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
//    exit(0);
//#endif
}

void HelloWorld::destroyNode()
{
    node_->destroy();
}
```

Comment: Post the error message and call stack. Don't assume anyone is going to run your code, definitely not without the entire project in "just open & run" format.

Comment: As @baskus's suggest, its a bad idea to destroy the node that CCCallFunc still keep a pointer (ref. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html), I will refactor the code to use the create/release paradigm instead of direct use new/delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this works on iOS but you should not do this anyway. When you run the code

```
CCCallFunc *selector = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(TestNode::destroy));
this->runAction(selector);
```

which calls the function

```
void TestNode::destroy()
{
    CCLog("+++ destroy");
    delete this;
}
```

you are destroying an object that the CCCallFunc action still keeps a pointer to. Then when the CCCallFunc object is destroyed, it runs the CC_SAFE_RELEASE macro which will call release on your TestNode object. However, by now that TestNode object is already deallocated and that is most likely the reason for your crash.